# Plot title overlays polar histogram - python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with a plot title that overlays a polar histogram in python.
I would like to display the plot title above the 'pi/2', how would I go about that?

Example of problem:

```py
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(polar=True)


N = 120
angles = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,8000)
distribution = np.histogram(angles, bins=N, range=(0.0, 2*np.pi))[0]
theta = (np.arange(N)+0.5)*2*np.pi/N
width = 2*np.pi / N # Width of bars
colors = plt.cm.hsv(theta/2/np.pi)


ax.bar(theta, distribution, width=width, color=colors)
ax.set_rticks([]) # Hides radius tics
ax.set_xticklabels([r'$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{4}$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$',r'$\frac{3\pi}{4}$',
                        r'$\pi$',r'$\frac{5\pi}{4}$',r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$',r'$\frac{7\pi}{4}$'])
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
ax.set_title('Polar histogram over angles')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pad` keyword which determines the space between the plot and title:

```
ax.set_title('Polar histogram over angles', pad=20)
```